# layout_alignBottom aligns center instead of bottom

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to get the bottom of my TextView and EditText to line up (perhaps not to the pixel, but close) inside of a RelativeLayout. But layout_alignBottom seems to line up their center line instead of their bottom:

[image]

I tried layout_alignBaseline also, but the result was that the EditText does not display on the screen. I also made various efforts at adjusting padding, but it didn't change anything. This seems like it should be easy and a common issue, but I couldn't find anything Googling. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstNameLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name" />

<EditText
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstNameLabel"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstNameLabel"
    android:id="@+id/firstName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstNameLabel"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <EditText
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstNameLabel"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:id="@+id/firstName"
         android:hint="YO BABY"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using android:layout_centerVertical="true" for the TextView improves the situation, in that they are no longer lined up exactly center. I'm still wondering if there is a way to line them up closer. Lining up elements vertically more exactly in a RelativeLayout would seem to be a common case.

Comment: you want to align the Bottom or center?

Comment: I want to align the bottom.

Comment: try to reduce the android:layout_marginRight="24dp" in TextView. They'll get closer.

Comment: Margin right affects horizontal alignment; my problem is vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin top from code and check

Comment: Thanks, but that no made no difference between the vertical alignment of the two elements relative to one another.

Answer (score 0):

What's causing this is the EditText being bigger than the textview. Check your layout that contains both and set the gravity to "center" or "center_vertical".

Edit: If you're using RelativeLayout, you should probably use "layout_centerVertical" or "layout_centerInParent" instead

Comment: I'm not trying to center the element vertically within the container. I position them at the top and try to align them vertically relative to one another.

Comment: Ah...in that case you can probably make use of another layout. Wrap the two views in another layout, align it to the top while centering the views within.